# How to copy data from non starting MBA?

Tags: hard-drive, macbook-pro, data

My old MBA (2008) is not booting anymore from hdd. I tried to repair it with disk repair and with a DiskWarrior CD-ROM, but nothing. I need to copy some data from the hdd, before replacing it.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I would started with getting that drive out of MBA with [the instruction from iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Air+Models+A1237+and+A1304+Hard+Drive+Replacement/860) for example.

Then I would buy one of [these IDE to 40 pin ZIF](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?LH_BIN=1&_from=R40%7CR40%7CR40%7CR40&_sacat=0&_nkw=40%20pin%20zif%20to%20ide&_sop=15) adapters and find yourself old PC or Mac with IDE connection.

Fire up DiskWarrior or R-Studio (on Windows) or better and cheaper with [DDRescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/).
If you want to check if HDD is physically sound you might also try MHDD or Victoria tools (they are DOS and Windows only though).

And if you want to replace that HDD better go with SSD. At least 64GB SSD will do big boost to this old bugger. Provided you have Nvidia in yours. If it is intel I would just replace HDD and sell it.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** This model doesn’t support TDM. A functionally equivalent alternative: you can remove the HDD from the machine and use an external drive enclosure to try and mount the disk as an external drive on another machine in the same fashion.

---

If you have access to another Mac and a Firewire cable (along with FW > Thunderbolt adapter if the Mac does not have FW port), you can attempt to mount the drive as an external drive on the other Mac using [Target Disk Mode.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Target_Disk_Mode) If the drive doesn’t mount, however, it’s more than likely bricked.

> "Target Disk Mode is useful for accessing the contents of a Mac which cannot be booted from its own operating system."

Data recovery companies offer costlier solutions and do not guarantee success. Weigh the cost/benefit of pursuing such, and consider this a last option. Best of luck.

Comment: This model doesn't have Firewire or Thunderbolt so you answer is completely off key.